# The address for STREET basemap

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

I am wondering where i can  find the map service address for basemap "street" found at \viewer\js\config\viewer.js ? (Configurable Map Service v 1.3.4)

```
>     define([    'esri/units',    'esri/geometry/Extent',    'esri/config', 'esri/tasks/GeometryService',   
> 'esri/layers/ImageParameters' ], function (units, Extent, esriConfig,
> GeometryService, ImageParameters) {
>     
>         // url to your proxy page, must be on same machine hosting you app. See proxy folder for readme.
>         esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = 'proxy/proxy.ashx';
>         esriConfig.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = false;
>         // url to your geometry server.
>         esriConfig.defaults.geometryService = new GeometryService('http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer');
>     
>         //image parameters for dynamic services, set to png32 for higher quality exports.
>         var imageParameters = new ImageParameters();
>         imageParameters.format = 'png32';
>     
>         return {
>             // used for debugging your app
>             isDebug: true,
>     
>             //default mapClick mode, mapClickMode lets widgets know what mode the map is in to avoid multipult map click actions from
> taking place (ie identify while drawing).
>             defaultMapClickMode: 'identify',
>             // map options, passed to map constructor. see: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#map1
>             mapOptions: {


        **basemap: 'streets',**  //where is it defined ?

>                 center: [-99.59179687497497, 139.09596293629694],
>                 zoom: 5,
>                 sliderStyle: 'small'
>             },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the comment right above that line -

> map options, passed to map constructor. see:
>   https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#map1

If you go to that link, you'll find [this page that lists all the options and the URLs](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.basemaps-amd.html#properties).